# JavaScript syntactic sugar when incrementing/decrementing variable

Tags: javascript, syntactic-sugar

> LeetCode 680. Valid Palindrome II Easy
>
> Given a string s, return true if the s can be palindrome after
> deleting at most one character from it.

Can someone tell me why the first code below is much faster than the second code? The only difference between them is how I'm incrementing and decrementing my variables in the isPalindrome function.

```
var validPalindrome = function (s) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = s.length - 1;
  while (left < right) {
    if (s[left] !== s[right]) {
      return isPalindrome(s, left + 1, right) || isPalindrome(s, left, right - 1);
    }
    left++;
    right--;
  }
  return true;
};

let isPalindrome = (s, left, right) => {
  while (left < right) {
    if (s[left++] !== s[right--]) { // writing it this way is much faster
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/*
Runtime: 72 ms, faster than 98.87% of JavaScript online submissions for Valid Palindrome II.
Memory Usage: 48.7 MB, less than 21.51% of JavaScript online submissions for Valid Palindrome II.
*/
```

```
var validPalindrome = function (s) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = s.length - 1;
  while (left < right) {
    if (s[left] !== s[right]) {
      return isPalindrome(s, left + 1, right) || isPalindrome(s, left, right - 1);
    }
    left++;
    right--;
  }
  return true;
};

let isPalindrome = (s, left, right) => {
  while (left < right) {
    if (s[left] !== s[right]) {
      return false;
    }
    left++; // this is slightly slower
    right--;
  }
  return true;
}

/*
Runtime: 116 ms, faster than 58.84% of JavaScript online submissions for Valid Palindrome II.
Memory Usage: 48.2 MB, less than 27.24% of JavaScript online submissions for Valid Palindrome II.
*/
```

```
Example 1:

Input: s = "aba"
Output: true
Example 2:

Input: s = "abca"
Output: true
Explanation: You could delete the character 'c'.
Example 3:

Input: s = "abc"
Output: false
```

Comment: You're talking about milliseconds. Is there a real issue here?

Comment: The measurements on LeetCode vary a lot, and are likely to be influenced by "external" factors, such as server load. Don't pay too much attention to them.

Comment: Intuitively I would expect the 2nd version to be faster, because it doesn't update the  variables in the iteration where `return false` happens.

Comment: leetcode in case of validating inputs is often - bad. For example - 1st time i tried the code for not really long string (that 1st iteration should tell - NOT PALINDROM) i got result after ~0.200ms  next ones were like 0.002 or so  (this is because of JIT). As for what its it faster for the code with inline changed values. Its mostly because they are not used anymore, and JIT could actually optimize the code even further. So it incremented/decremented variables, used new values, and went to the if next try. In earlier version - use old vlaues, inc/dec, use new values for while, repeat

Comment: accidently checked this code:

Comment: var validPalindrome = function (s) {
  let left = -1;
  let right = s.length;
  const unEvenString = (s.length & 1 === 1);
  // if (unEvenString) return false; // uncomment if uneven string should not be palindrom
  while (left < right) {
    if (s[++left] !== s[--right]) {
      return false
    }
  }
    
  return true;
};

Comment: and it is said to test the basic test in 99ms, which is total BS as it even is less code and tasks that yours code did - so HOW it can be even slower? (i have played with the numers pre andpost increments much more there - and the given timings are just sad